# PDKeychainBindingsController: how to reset items in keychain?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I am using PDKeychainBindingsController, but it has no method to resetAllKeychainItems as the Apple's KeychainItemWrapper, can anyone tell me how to perform the same task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new method:

```
- (void)resetKeychainItems {
     bindings = [PDKeychainBindings sharedKeychainBindings];
     [bindings removeObjectForKey:@"..."];
     [bindings removeObjectForKey:@"..."];
      ...
 }
```

Comment: Yes this method can remove the value for a key, but I need a way to remove all keychain data for the app.

Comment: Also we need to explicitly remove them.Its not being removed when app is uninstalled. why so?